# Symfony 3 Bad credentials while login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I got a problem setting up a login with Symfony 3.
I don't use FOSUserBundle because I need to log with the email only. I've been trying to create an user through my controller, it's working fine and add my user in my DB, but the authentification always show me the "Bad credentials" error.

Here is my User entity :

```
<?php
namespace GR\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="utilisateur")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GR\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $telephone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $salt = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
     */
    private $roles = array();

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GR\BackOfficeBundle\Entity\Client", inversedBy="utilisateurs")
     */
    private $client;

    //getters & setters + UserInterface empty methods
```

Here is my security.yml file :

```
security:

    encoders:
        GR\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_OPERATEUR, ROLE_COLLABORATEUR]
        ROLE_OPERATEUR: ROLE_COLLABORATEUR
        ROLE_COLLABORATEUR: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_DESTINATAIRE: ROLE_USER
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        back_office:
            entity:
                class: GR\UserBundle\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        back_office_login:
            pattern: ^/back-office/login$
            anonymous: true
            provider: back_office
            form_login:
                login_path: gr_bo_login
                check_path: gr_bo_login_check
                default_target_path: gr_bo_home

        back_office:
            pattern: ^/back-office
            anonymous: false
            provider: back_office
            form_login:
                login_path: gr_bo_login
                check_path: gr_bo_login_check
                default_target_path: gr_bo_home
            logout:
                path: gr_bo_logout
                target: gr_bo_login
            remember_me:
                secret: "%secret%"
```

Here is my login form :

```
{% extends "GRUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block log_content %}
    {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('gr_bo_login_check') }}" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email :</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="_email" />

        <label for="password">Mot de passe :</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Connexion" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is what I did to create my user :

```
$user = new User();

$user->setNom('Test');
$user->setEmail('admin@admin.fr');
$user->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
$user->setPassword('admin');
$encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
$encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());
$user->setPassword($encoded);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

I encoded my user password according to [this doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/password_encoding.html)

In my DB, the user created is like this :

```
id: 4
client_id : null
nom : Test
telephone: null
email : admin@admin.fr
password : nhDr7OyKlXQju+Ge/WKGrPQ9lPBSUFfpK+B1xqx/+8zLZqRNX0+5G1zBQklXUFy86lCpkAofsExlXiorUcKSNQ==
salt: 
roles: a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}
```

Now I don't know what to do, what can I try to make this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) you can add another service like [username_email](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/logging_by_username_or_email.html) that provide to connect with email or username, so that may be a good inspiration for your project,  create your own service by [reuse or overwrite security file in this bundle in the same way](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/security.xml) of the current FOSUserBundle.

Comment: Well, I tried it, it works, but I tried it before, and it wasn't working, that's why I uninstalled FOSUserBundle, and now I reinstall it and it's working. I feel stupid, but at leastmy problem is solved, thank's